# Why training is good but cannot predict anything even the training samples

Tags: python, image, keras, unet-neural-network

I use a u-net model to train some pictures in which there are 3 defects, the loss is "categorical_crossentropy" and matric is IOU(intersection over union) between predict and truth. When I finished trainging ,the result is good, IOU reaches 87% and loss is below 7.4443e-04, but after predction, it got nothing, even if tesing the trainining samples. Below is the testing code comparing the true labels and predict labels.

```
a = 0
for i in training.label_name_val:   
    if '\\' in i and a<100:
        a+=1
        raw_img = cv2.imread(i.replace('.png','.bmp'),0)
        image=np.expand_dims(raw_img,axis=2)
        img = np.zeros((1,608,528,1),dtype=np.float32)
        img[0,:,:,:] = np.array(image/255,dtype='float32')
        mask = cv2.imread(i)
        infer_img = training.model.predict(img,batch_size=16)
        infer_img = np.argmax(infer_img,axis=-1)
        plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
        plt.subplot(1,3,1)
        plt.imshow(mask)
        plt.subplot(1,3,2)
        plt.title(np.unique(infer_img))
        plt.imshow(infer_img[0,:,:],cmap='jet')
```

the result: left is true label, right is predict label.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngWD2.png)

Here I add part of the result array, it seems the ok prediction(first) is nearly 1, and defects prediction(latter 3 numbers) is nearly 0. It's quite different from the logic of training result.

```
[[[[1.00000000e+00 1.53722974e-21 4.75415969e-17 5.70772332e-32]
   [1.00000000e+00 1.90659765e-31 5.15209822e-23 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 1.34475142e-34 2.92512058e-26 0.00000000e+00]
   ...
   [1.00000000e+00 1.35033362e-27 9.07716726e-20 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 4.04645854e-23 1.60991434e-15 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 3.18021596e-13 1.09597352e-10 4.99951517e-22]]

  [[1.00000000e+00 6.41531835e-37 7.19892247e-28 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.90926201e-38 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   ...
   [1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.11940014e-30 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.47139768e-25 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 5.32593445e-23 8.56831213e-16 1.92205218e-36]]

  [[1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   ...
   [1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.01963658e-32 0.00000000e+00]
   [1.00000000e+00 4.66948815e-31 3.11143341e-20 0.00000000e+00]]

  ...
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail? You are taking the argmax over the final dimension of the model output. What are the dimensions of the model output? Also, imshow typically takes a tensor with three dimensions, being the height, width, and channels, but you seem to be inputting two. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Since there're 3 defects, there are total 4 layers in the model output plus the ok layer. And imshow can takes two dimensions consisting of height and width as gray picture.

Comment: I add some of the results.

Comment: What happens when you try this same code to visualize the model output on training samples, in a case where the loss on the sample was low, i.e., the model correctly predicted?

Comment: I tried 100 training samples and only 5 of them can predict something(but the region is too small compared with the truth), and  the others is nothing but ok.